# How to send an xml file through email in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: xml, azure, email, cloud, azure-logic-apps

I have some xml data that I want to send as an xml file through email in azure logic apps. However, it seems like there is no way for me to even have the file sent through email as an attachment. Does anyone know of any connectors available that will let me do it? Or some type of workaround?

Comment: Poor quality question, provide the code and what the kind of problem you encounter, rather than asking advice (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

On "Send an email" you have "Attachments Content 1" and "Attachments Name 1" properties, to add attachments to your email. Do you have any problem with this connector?

[image]